# how to fix c++ memory leaks?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have code like this, when `class A` manages an object `B` and `vector<shared_ptr<B>>`, then I create a `A`from a static method, when I do this, I think if `A::returnA()` goes out of scope, then `A::returnA()` will be deleted, then `B` that's managed by `A` is deleted, then `vector<shared_ptr<B>>` is deleted.

However, when I run this code, the memory usage displayed in monitor is huge, and continue increasing, I don't know why this is leaking memory.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    static A returnA(){
        return A();
    }
    class B {
    public:
        ~B() { cout << "~B" << endl; }
    };
    B b;
    vector<std::shared_ptr<B>> v;
    A(){
        std::unique_ptr<B> b2 = make_unique<B>();
        v.emplace_back(new B());
    };
    ~A() { cout << "~A" << endl; }
};

int main() {
    while(1){
        A::returnA();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/~vector

Comment: @qbit but those are smart pointers.. i thought they will delete the object ..they didn't delete them?

Comment: What is the actual output? Do you see a lot of "~A" "~B"?

Comment: @Tas yes, but the memory usage displayed in the monitor is continue increasing.

Comment: FYI I [edited your question] to include a [mcve] for your code (which was just including files). This is to aid people helping you; however, if my changes are not demonstrative of your code you should [edit] your question to fix my changes.

Comment: @Tas if all the memory are freed , we may expected that the memory usage will have some upper boundary. the monitor lied??

Comment: The example in your question looks fine.  The fact that your vector holds `shared_ptr`s leads me to think that maybe in your real code they are actually shared with something.  Maybe there's some sort of circular ownership somewhere?

Comment: This code doesn't compile. There is no such header `iosream`. Please make sure you copy and paste the EXACT code you used to generate the bogus behaviour.

Comment: @M.M that was my fault <_< I updated OP's code to include the includes, so it was a mcve, but I made a mistake. I've fixed it now.

Comment: @Tas all the same; the code as posted now doesn't actually have a leak so most likely it is not OP's code and they should post their code

Comment: If there are memory leaks Valgrind will help you detect it. Make sure the shared pointers aren't held somewhere else as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your screenshot does not show the memory of your app. It shows the memory of Xcode. It's Xcode that's taking up so much memory, possibly because it's keeping the log of `cout` so you can scroll through it.